# Applying AM-GM to bound $(1+x/n)^n$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Given $-x < n < m$ where $n,m$ are positive integers, apply the [arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) to show:

$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \leq(1+\frac{x}{m})^m$

My first instinct was to split $n + x$ into the sum of $n$ terms and apply AM-GM but that didn't seem to get me any closer. Since we only know that $x+m > x+n >0$ are positive so AM-GM cannot be applied directly in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n+1$ numbers, $1$ once and $1+\dfrac{x}{n}$ taken $n$ times. By AM-GM inequality, we have,
$$\dfrac{1+n\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)}{1+n}>\left(1\times\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n\right)^\frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$\iff1+\dfrac{x}{n+1}>\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^\frac{n}{n+1}$$
$$\iff \left(1+\dfrac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}>\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
Hence, the sequence $\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n$ is strictly increasing (because equality cannot hold for any non-zero $x$), now your result follows.

Comment: Martund. Nice answer.

Comment: Useful technique for other problems too, thank you!